# Emacs Org-mode: How to include properties in diary anniversaries?

Tags: emacs, properties, calendar, elisp, org-mode

I am trying to have the "Birthday" and "Name" properties of an Org-mode entry added to the agenda automatically:

```
* John
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Name: John
  :Birthday: (5 4 1900)
  :END:
```

I found a way to add an entry at the correct anniversary date in the agenda by inserting the following line right after the properties:

```
%%(apply 'diary-anniversary (read (org-entry-get nil "Birthday"))) John
```

However, using this code, I still have to enter the name manually. Is there a way to have the value of the "Name" property added to the diary text automatically for all entries?

**EDIT 1**: the example did not work before, now added parantheses around the value of the birthday property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe https://julien.danjou.info/projects/emacs-packages#org-contacts is the solution to your problem. org-contacts is a address book for org-mode.

Comment: As of 2011-05-17, the link for org-contacts doesn't show how to obtain in.  The web page currently says it ships with org-mode version > 7.5 but the current version of org-mode is 7.5

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment earlier. Org-mode 7.6 was released on July 6th.  Before the only way to get the latest version of org-contacts would have been to clone the [org-mode repo](http://orgmode.org/w/org-mode.git): `git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git`.

Comment: Then change into the repo `cd org-mode` and build org-mode: `make clean && make`.

As a last step you have to tell emacs about the org-mode-repo. Put `(setq load-path (cons "/path/to/repo/org-mode/lisp" (cons "/path/to/repo/org-mode/contrib/lisp" load-path))` and `(require 'org-contacts)` to your **~/.emacs**.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably better to ask this at the [Org mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode), they are very active, and Carsten Dominik (the creator of org-mode) usually answers posts on this list almost immediately (BTW, [this](http://Emacs-orgmode@gnu.org) is the main list email.

Comment: I had come across the list already. Your suggestion is good, though it should have been a comment to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you a taking a path which requires you to write some lisp to get what you want. The org-mode manual gives an example of something similar, but I'm guessing you wanted a simpler format, when it describes the calendar/agenda integration http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Weekly_002fdaily-agenda.html

```
* Birthdays and similar stuff
 #+CATEGORY: Holiday
 %%(org-calendar-holiday)   ; special function for holiday names
 #+CATEGORY: Ann
 %%(diary-anniversary 14  5 1956) Arthur Dent is %d years old
 %%(diary-anniversary  2 10 1869) Mahatma Gandhi would be %d years old
```

I would think you have other options if you want a custom setup: either a new type of export or dynamic blocks might be used.  This may highlight the different use-case of agenda over the diary.  The agenda seems more geared towards day to day tasks.

Comment: This comes close to what I am already doing and what I tried to describe in my question. I would like to have the names "Arthur Dent" and "Mahatma Gandhi" inserted in the agenda automatically by extracting the value of the "Name" property.